# How to Display Time(7) in Razor View Netcore?

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, razor

I have a view to display a field `time(7)` in SQL Database to User:

[image]

The values in the database are like this:

[image]

And I just want to display the time in format `hh:mm` only.

How can I do this?

I have tried but it failed:

```
@item.TimeMatch.ToString("hh:mm")
```

Comment: "The values in the database are like this:"
Did you forget to include them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the solution
@item.TimeMatch.ToString(@"hh:mm")

Comment: In the raw text of your answer, you typed `@"hh\:mm"` (with backlash). Is there supposed to be a backslash in the final answer? Also is this second `@` symbol supposed to be there?